# Issues with jQuery UI modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm trying to initiate a jQuery UI modal window, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function () {
    $("#k2superform").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        draggable: false,
        closeText: false,
        minWidth: 600,
        zIndex: 99,
        modal: true
    });
    $(".triggerk2form").click(function () {
        $("#k2superform").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
}); });
```

Here is the HTML code. (It is for a joomla K2 component. It used to have a mootools squeezebox modal window.)

```
    <span class="catItemEditLink">
    <a class="triggerk2form" rel="{handler:'iframe',size:{x:990,y:650}}" href="<?php echo $this->item->editLink; ?>">
        <?php echo JText::_('Edit item'); ?>
    </a>
</span>
```

Comment: What about telling us what is not working?

Comment: jquery ui modal window is not working - not initiating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out the code you provided, stripping off the server-side script, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Rbybe/.

It might be that the PHP script has some unescaped code. Could you post the rendered HTML instead?

Comment: Hey William, lol tottally forgot to chnage newsletter_module  in this code :)

Comment: Hey William, tottally forgot to change #newsletter_module in here, anyways it was not a problem.  Problem is with jquery ui modal window not initiating at all.